# Getting name of the image which is on the image view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

Is there any way to get the name of the image which is present on the image view which is there on my screen. Please tell me ways to do this. I already searched it a lot but still have not found anything useful. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass UIImageView and add a property name or identifier.

```
@interface MyImageView : UIImageView{
    NSString *name;
}
@property (retain) NSString *name;
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image andName:(NSString *)name;
@end;


@implementation MyImageView
@synthesize name;
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image andName:(NSString *)name
{
    if(self = [super initWithImage:image]){
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)dealloc
{
   self.name = nil;
   [super dealloc;]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the tag property of the view to distinguish between different imageViews.

Comment: but i want to get hte name ,using tag i am not able to get taht

Comment: but with the tag you cab keep track of the name you save elsewhere.

Comment: but i am not getting the name using the tag as well

Comment: Store the name in a dictionary where the key is the tag of the image view.

Comment: that is what I meant with *but with the tag you cab keep track of the name you save elsewhere.*